# ASP.NET MVC ValidationSummary For Client Side Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Our server side validation (via data annotations) is working great and posts the errors in our ValidationSummary how we like it.  The client side validation also works, however the errors display to the right of the control and the validation summary never displays.  Is there an easy way to make the client validation display to look like that of server side validation display?

Comment: You are using ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2?

Comment: Too little information to give an answer.

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2.  Using data annotation on entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about using ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2 or any other generated client side validation that uses the [jQuery Validation library](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), you should check out `errorLabelContainer` and `errorContainer` in the [documentation for jQuery Validation library](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).

That should get your client side validation looking more like the server side validation summary. :-)

HTHs,
Charles

Ps. If you can't alter the `$('myForm').Validate()`'s options, just use the `$.validator.setDefaults();` approach. Although you could get into trouble with more than one form / validation summary on a page.

Comment: Could you please elaborate just a litte more here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's good practice to use with ASP.NET MVC 2, but with [xVal](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/09/17/xval-v10-now-available/) cliend side validation summary is easy to do.

```
<div id="validationSummary">
        <%= Html.ValidationSummary("Please fix the following problems:") %>
</div>

<%= Html.ClientSideValidation("booking", typeof(Booking))
        .UseValidationSummary("validationSummary") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that for the model object being validated that the `.Error` property from the `IDataErrorInfo` interface is not `String.Empty`. This might cause the behaviour you seem to be having.