# Asp.Net MVC - Change error class name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, xval

When I do field validation in Asp.Net MVC, it's generated the following error css classes :

- input-validation-error
- field-validation-error

Is there a way that I can change the names of the error classes that are generated?

I use xVal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know about xVal but as far as the ASP.NET MVC side of things go, if you have a look at [the source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/21528#266468) you'll see there are some static readonly strings that represent these values.

```
public static readonly string ValidationInputCssClassName = "input-validation-error";
public static readonly string ValidationMessageCssClassName = "field-validation-error";
public static readonly string ValidationSummaryCssClassName = "validation-summary-errors";
```

So either you edit the source to your liking (which may also fix xVal) or alter the outputting code to use different values somehow.

If xVal is using jQuery Validation (which I think it does...?) you could change it's default value for the 'errorClass' option. [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724790/asp-net-mvc-validationsummary-for-client-side-validation/1726913#1726913) could help you along that path.

HTHs,
Charles

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did:

```
private void ChangeValidationClassNames()
{
    var helper = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(), new ViewPage());
    SetPublicStaticReadonly("ValidationInputCssClassName", helper, "errInput");
    SetPublicStaticReadonly("ValidationMessageCssClassName", helper, "errMsg");
}

public void SetPublicStaticReadonly(string readonlyPropName, object instance, object value)
{            
    var field = instance.GetType().GetField(readonlyPropName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    if (field == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException(string.Format("public static readonly field '{0}' not found in '{1}'", readonlyPropName, instance));
    field.SetValue(instance, value);
}
```

Comment: @TweetZz: you don't need an HtmlHelper instance to change static fields. you can get the field just from `typeof(HtmlHelper)`, and call `SetValue(null, value)`.

Answer (score 0):

More cleaner solution may be:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.input-validation-error').addClass('CustomErrorClass').removeClass('input-validation-error');
        $('.field-validation-error').addClass('CustomErrorClass').removeClass('field-validation-error');
    });
</script>
```