# MVC2 ValidationSummary and Client side Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2-validation

I want to have the ValidationSummary errors displayed during Client Side validation. Currently the validation messages are only appears next to the field during client side validation. I use….

1. MicrosoftAjax.js
2. MicrosoftMvcAjax.js
3. MicrosoftMvcValidation.js

as my client side libraries.

There is a solution for jQuery Validation Library which is in the thread…
[ASP.NET MVC ValidationSummary For Client Side Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724790/asp-net-mvc-validationsummary-for-client-side-validation)

Is there an easy way to do this?

I used had xVal working DataAnnotation and it was very easy enable client side validation for the validation summary.

E.g

Is there way to do this in MVC2 using MicrosoftAjax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I see is specified in the below article. Honestly why would anyone try getting validation summary control working for client side with MicrosoftAjax when there is a nice solution.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025164158/http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/27/asp.net-mvc-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-plugin.aspx)

My 2cents.